# Recursively estimated volatility of returns

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I would like recursively compute the volatility (standard deviation) of returns, that is for date t only use data up to t.

I have data in the following format:

```
my_data <- data.frame(Date = 2001:2005, Return_1 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3), Return_2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.6))
```

and suggestively the output would be a new data frame only the return columns would be the volatility values.

Thank you for any help in how I can approach this.

Comment: See if this [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14810/how-to-calculate-stock-volatility-in) post answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
sd_up_to_date = data.frame(lapply(my_data[,-1],function(ret) sapply(seq_along(ret),function(time_point) sd(ret[1:time_point]))))

str(sd_up_to_date)
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Return_1: num  NA 0.0707 0.1 0.0957 0.0837
 $ Return_2: num  NA 0.0707 0.2082 0.1893 0.2345
```

Explanation:

`lapply(my_data[,-1],function(ret) ...` = consider each of the elements of my_data except the first (so, the 'returns')

`sapply(seq_along(ret),function(time_point) sd(ret[1:time_point]))` = consider each time_point along each vector of returns, and calculate the standard deviation (sd()) from the first element up to that one

`data.frame( ... )` = make the whole thing into a data.frame

Note that the sd of a single time point is NA, so all the first elements are NA.
After that, 0.0707 is sd(c(0.2,0.3)), 0.1 is sd(c(0.2,0.3,0.4)), and so on...